# Meteor nodets:mysql custom query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, meteor

Can anyone help me to write custom query in meteor `nodets:mysql` package ?
Like right now I am trying to execute `query Parties.find();` but how can I run the custom `MySQL` queries from that package.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation I see this:

```
Users = db.meteorCollection("users","usersCollection",criteria);
//criteria object offers you executing select queries to the mysql database.
//Use it if you need to return only specific columns or joined tables.
```

It doesn't go any further in explaining, but you probably just put your custom sql in criteria, such as

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ..."
```

I would try it and see what you get.

Otherwise use this package, which looks to be closer to SQL anyway - https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql

Comment: Thanks, i will check that. Kindly can you tell me how can i get the publish count in numtel:mysql package ? Or how can i use tmeasday:publish-counts in numtel package ?

Comment: Afraid I don't know, you'll have to play with it and see

Comment: Thanks. :) has been playing with it but not succeeded yet. btw i am using vlasky:mysql version which uses numtel:mysql but with subscribe method.